# Is it possible to interject your own audio once the ios media library has taken over?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, audio-player

I am wondering if it would be possible to insert your own audio once the ios media library has taken over in an app?

Example: Playing a piece of audio after every song that says the number of songs you've listened to that day.

I know that because its a framework there is only so many things they let you do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be doable. To start, you can add your class as an observer of the `MPMusicPlayerControllerNowPlayingItemDidChangeNotification` to be informed when the song in the iPod library changes. From there, you can tell the iPod library to pause, play your track, and then resume music playback afterwards.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(someSel:) name:MPMusicPlayerControllerNowPlayingItemDidChangeNotification object:nil];


[[MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer] pause];
    // play your sound
[[MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer] play];
```

Comment: That's fantatsic! I assume you're an awesome obj-c dev. I'm just getting into it myself and am looking for a mentor. If you'd like to mentor me now and then let me know!